# EventMachine for concurrent tcp connections not working

Tags: ruby, sockets, tcp

Trying to do concurrent TCP connections, but the following code snippet didn't send TCP connection request (TCP SYN) at the same time. According to wireshark, it waited for one TCP connection to establish before doing the next.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'eventmachine'

class Echo < EventMachine::Connection
  def post_init
    send_data "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n"
  end

  def receive_data(data)
    puts data
  end
end

EventMachine.run {
    EventMachine::connect 'www.google.com', 80, Echo
    EventMachine::connect 'www.google.com', 80, Echo
}
```

I would need to be able to do thousands of concurrent TCP requests at the sametime, so didn't try using ruby threads.

Comment: see [EventMachine::Iterator](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/eventmachine/eventmachine/EventMachine/Iterator) and  [EventMachine and Looping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030976/eventmachine-and-looping)

Comment: Thx for the links but they don't show how to do two TCP requests at the same time (without waiting one to finish before starting another).